# How to specify the Deployer temp storage location?

Tags: content-delivery, java

We've noticed that the Deployer uses the Java temp directory to store zip packages whilst deploying, this is confirmed by the Deployer log file:

> +56  2013-12-04 19:54:40,919 INFO  Deployer - java.io.tmpdir = /tmp/

We're wondering if there's a way to configure this path, rather than taking the `java.io.tmpdir`.  It isn't causing a problem, we just don't like using this path and would like to be able to configure it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The temp location is configurable via `cd_storage_conf.xml`.

The `Storages` element takes an attribute called `TempFileSystemTransactionLocation`.  For example:

```
<Storages TempFileSystemTransactionLocation="/apps01/tridion_deployer_tmp"> 
        <Storage Type="persistence" Id="sqlserver" dialect="MSSQL" Class="com.tridion.storage.persistence.JPADAOFactory">
            <Pool Type="jdbc" Size="5" MonitorInterval="60" IdleTimeout="120" CheckoutTimeout="120" />
            <DataSource Class="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDataSource">
                <Property Name="serverName" Value="localhost" />
                <Property Name="portNumber" Value="1433" />
                <Property Name="databaseName" Value="Tri_Live" />
                <Property Name="user" Value="TridionBrokerUser" />
                <Property Name="password" Value="nunyabidness" />
            </DataSource>
        </Storage>
        <Storage Type="filesystem" Class="com.tridion.storage.filesystem.FSDAOFactory" Id="tomcatFS" defaultFilesystem="false">
            <Root Path="/apps01/websites/tri_live" />
        </Storage>
</Storages>
```

This can be confirmed by looking at the `cd_storage_conf.xsd` file inside the `cd_core.jar`, which has the following:

```
<xsd:attribute name="TempFileSystemTransactionLocation" type="xsd:string" use="optional">
    <xsd:annotation>
        <xsd:documentation>
            <p>This is used as temporal storage for filesystem transactions for all file system storages ('java.io.tmpdir' Java system property is used by default).</p>
        </xsd:documentation>
    </xsd:annotation>
</xsd:attribute>
```

Answer (score 5):

You have a few options:

- Start the Deployer JVM with system property `java.io.tmpdir` set to whatever you want;

> Example: `java -Djava.io.tmpdir=C:\MyTemp com.tridion.deployer.Deployer`

- On Windows, set the environment variable `TMP` to a custom value. The Java JVM uses this value as default (when you don't specify the system property `java.io.tmpdir`). If you are on Linux, apparently you cannot rely on environment variables (according to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1924136/environment-variable-to-control-java-io-tmpdir);

Comment: Hi Mihai, I suspect that's possible, but i'm talking as a configuration element of the deployer - thanks john

Comment: I'm not sure there is such configuration. The only thing you configure is the `incoming` location where the HTTPSReceiver stores incoming packages and the queue location where the deployer picks them up from.

Answer (score 3):

This setting is not configurable in the Deployer configuaration, it is as Mihai mentions down to the JVM startup arguments.

When you start the Deployer as a service, it would be easy enough to specify the `-Djava.io.tmpdir` parameter there, but when using the HTTP(S) Deployer in a Web application, then you will have to ensure it's JVM has this parameter set.

This is described in the documentation under the chapter: [Configuring the JVM for Windows services and .NET Web applications](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Tridion%20full%20documentation-v1/GUID-5163B30C-F33E-4648-A887-A50BA86B573D) ([requires login](http://docportal.sdl.com/sdltridion)).

To configure the JVM settings for your Windows services and .NET Web applications you have to add these to the registry in the `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Tridion\Content Delivery\General` subkey. For Apache Tomcat, IBM WebSphere and Oracle WebLogic you will have to check the vendors documentation on how to set JVM arguments.

Comment: Actually, this isn't true.  See my answer: http://tridion.stackexchange.com/a/10959/159